# Can't find valid/complete documentation for api.onedrive.com

Tags: javascript, onedrive

Working on a JavaScript based app (VueJS at moment) and am needing to navigate through a user's OneDrive account to find and select files. Documentation that I have found all seems to be for Microsoft's graph API, which uses a different auth method to what api.onedrive.com uses.

So far the only endpoint I have working correctly is "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children" and have been un-able to step out from there.

Any help on finding the list of endpoints and how to use them would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found interesting info about it in the following web.

[OneDrive Examples for Node.js](https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/onedrive.asp)